# Why are Google Geocoding API calls data not visible on the Dashboard in Google API Console?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

We have developed a website which makes server-side requests using Google Maps Geocoding API. However, the usage data is not reported on the Dashboard in the Google API Console.

Data is missing from the Dashboard only when the API is used using Client ID and Digital Signature (via Crypto key), which is what should be done for server-side requests as per advice from Google Personnel.

On the other hand, if we use the same API using an API key (instead of Client ID and Digital Signature) the usage data reflects fine on the Dashboard in the Google API Console.

Can anyone help me with information about what we are missing? How or where will API usage data be visible in case client ID and digital signature (via crypto key) is used?

Thanks

Aman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a client ID the usage data will be visible in your Cloud support portal with 24h delay.

There is detailed explanation regarding reports that you can see for your Premium plan using client ID or API key in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/reports/

Hope it helps!